# If I reach 10k reputation and then give much of it away in bounties will I still have moderator privileges?

Tags: discussion, reputation, moderation, privileges

Basically, my question is as the title asks. If I get to 10k reputation and then give away reputation points bring me below 10k, will I still have access to moderator tools?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Why are privileges reversed when the deduction came from starting a bounty?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21299/why-are-privileges-reversed-when-the-deduction-came-from-starting-a-bounty) This one seems to be a duplicate: [Does a user lose privilege if his reputation decreases below requirement by giving a bounty?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8410/does-a-user-lose-privilege-if-his-reputation-decreases-below-requirement-by-givi)

Answer (score 4):

No.

If you win a million dollar prize, and then donate half of it to some charity supporting set theorists from Math.SE and MathOverflow, will you still have a million dollars? (Assuming that you had less than half a million to begin with, of course...)

Also on meta.SE, [Notify user when setting a bounty will revoke a privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11930/notify-user-when-setting-a-bounty-will-revoke-a-privilege), for example. Or [Can you lose an ability if your reputation falls below a threshold?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67847/can-you-lose-an-ability-if-your-reputation-falls-below-a-threshold)... and many others [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bprivileges%5D+bounty) and in other search parties over there.

Comment: Is this an opinion or what is actually coded? One doesn't need to assume that reputation is like money. ;-)

Comment: No, this is actually coded. You can try and give out some 3.9k in bounties over the next week or two and see what happens to your privileges. Or just wait until you hit 10k, then give the least bounty that will bring you under, so you're at most 50 points away from being back. The code just compares how much reputation you *have*. Not how much you *had at some point*.

Comment: Also, money allows you to do things that you cannot do otherwise. Money buys you privileges in our society. It's sad, but it's true (and luckily, for us, money is not the only thing that buys you privileges). If you lose your money, often you will lose some of your privileges. For example, I have enough money to privilege myself to fancy bottles of whisky. if I lose all my money, I'm afraid that I will have to do with cheap bottles of whisky, or something like that. That is a privilege I will lose if I lose my money.

Comment: You really like comparing rep to money! I would submit that it'd be better if once the 10k mark was hit then moderation tools would remain. The way I see it, hitting the 10k mark is a way of vetting the user to make sure they are invested in the good of math SE. Giving away significant bounties is only good for the site as it only drives higher quality content. That'd would be worth rewarding.

Comment: I don't like it. I just started with this analogy, and I'm too lazy to find a better one. Besides, it's important to know how to argue for a point of view that you think is "just reasonable, even if not perfect". And your argument, while valid and compelling fails the simplicity test. It will require the software to start checking if the user "is supposed to have" enough reputation or not, and if the user is such and such or this and that and so on and so forth. Far simpler is to test: Does the user have this much reputation? Yes, give access; no, deny it. Elegance and simplicity, above all.

Comment: It's not complicated at all. If the 10k threshold is exceeded then a boolean flag is set that remains set. In fact, a flag might already be used and in that case the corresponding else-clause would be removed and it would require less code. Actually, this is how it works with badges at the present, as you can't lose them: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58053/is-it-possible-to-lose-badges

Comment: @nayrb, maybe so, but user "privileges" have always been tied to rep ever since the beginning (and thus giving a 500 bounty when you have exactly 10k rep revokes your access until you reach 10k again); this has been discussed *ad nauseam* on meta.SE, so I would suggest that you pass your suggestions there if you think your proposals have merit. [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785) is a very succinct  version of Asaf's.

Comment: @nayrb: Firstly, you *can* lose tag badges, for the same reason that you are losing privileges. Secondly, badges are fields that added to your SQL entry, or however you want to think about the database. If you truly feel that your suggestion is "the right thing", feel free to bring it up with the management. This is way above my pay grade here. I'm just telling you what I know and understand about the current system. But don't expect your proposal to be accepted in good spirit. If you look at the search link I gave, you'll see this is a recurring theme.

Comment: I don't feel strongly enough about this to petition management. I plan to give away many bounties some time in the future but I wasn't sure if I should try for 10k first. It appears there is no reason to do so. I find your vigor in arguing over this Asaf a little amusing, if I may say so. =)

Comment: @nayrb: I'm not arguing about this. I'm replying with the same vigor as you do, plus epsilon (which requires me very little actual energy). You keep insisting that it has to be a good idea, I keep insisting that it isn't a very practical idea, and that it can be seen as philosophically wrong, depending on the approach you take to reputation and privileges. If you think that I'm putting any energy beyond typing, you're fairly wrong. :-)

Comment: I don't see what is philosophically wrong or hard to implement in @nayrb suggestion, except inertia.  It sounds more logical and beneficial than the current system of tying everying to reputation.  Implementation would only require SE to store another integer (greater than or equal to the reputation, and not displayed) representing a user's privilege level measured in points, and use that where reputation is currently used to set privileges.  Or a collection of binary flags as SE already does for some of the mod/dev/admin accounts that have priveleges independent of reputation.

Comment: @zyx: Inertia is a very strong state of things. And yes, admittedly, there are some "philosophical benefits" to such an approach, and yes, admittedly, it is not *that* difficult to implement if you add a Boolean field (and I didn't think of that when I wrote my previous comment, sure). However, depending on one's philosophical outlook, one will argue that tying things to reputation is not a *bad* thing either. And if you want to give a lot of bounties, that's your decree, just like it is your decree to give 30% of your paycheck to the Salvation Army. Just don't complain when you can't pay rent

Comment: Rate-limiting the bounties makes sense, but there is no special reason that it should be done through reputation, unless Stackexchange *wants* to make reputation more currency-like.    If they do want that, then in monetary and economic terms, a more correct algorithm is for awarded bounties to count as the equivalent number of upvotes, and for all bounties to count as a posting of some approximately equivalent (in front page utilization) number of questions.

Comment: @zyx: If the bounty was divided by 10, and it would say "Award 5 votes" or "Award 10 votes" or "Award 50 votes", would that be better in your case? As a mathematician you should know that it's about the same as a store writing "Costs 100 cents" or "Costs 1 dollar".

Comment: Well, if reputation is the standard of everything, then the/a displayed number next to a question or answer could be the reputation value of the post instead of the (up minus down) count.   This would also be in line with the money-ization idea.... if that is what SE really wants.  I think that they may not, and the bounty system stays the same because the effort to change it is perceived as not worth the trouble.

Comment: @nayrb what if the points are "lost"  due to vote invalidation or the user drawing penalties for posting offensive content, would you then also be in favor the user keeps their privileges? If not, I do think it is fair to say the logic of it would become more complex if bounties would be special cased. // Separately, if  points basically loose all value once threshold is passed it could (at least in theory) lead to 'passing points around' as a form of gaming the system. You give me 600 in bounties so that I get 25k privileges then I give you back this +1k interest for your 10k priv. Deal? ;D

Comment: @quid My feeling is that reaching 10k is hard enough that the likelihood of getting there from a vast number of vote invalidation is small. Besides, being vetted at 9k or 10k isn't much of a difference. Penalties for offensive content is a moderation issue so I don't see why a flag couldn't be turned off by a moderator. Passing around bounties does sound like an issue, though that could be screened for, and I also suspect a prisoner's dilemma effect could limit this.

Comment: If bounties are treated as upvotes (or proportional to upvotes) then controlling that becomes part of the "suspicious voting" algorithmic tests.  On the other hand the game @quid proposes can also be played in the current system in the form of patronage by high reputation users, who might trade points to purchase things like support on meta, or open/close votes.  The bounties already are a deviation from the basic philosophy of reputation as evaluation by the community (vs one user) and this can lead to games as long as only the bounty awarder  determines the number of points given.

Comment: Though to be honest, implementing this feature would be worth it itself if it resulted in a reputation sharing cartel being busted! What a scandal that would be. It'd be kind of like billionaires passing their money around different banks. =)

Comment: @nayrb: So you're suggesting *more* work for the unpaid volunteers?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Marking offensive content?

Comment: @nayrb: No, that is not necessarily a moderator's job. Users can mark offensive content. You're suggesting that moderators have to periodically make sure that users that received penalties for offensive/spam flags lose their moderation abilities when they reach below the threshold.

Comment: @nayrb: And what happens if a user has received a penalty, and then crosses the threshold again. Do they get their privileges back, or do they need to compensate by another X points? And if they do get their privileges back, and then post offensive content again, what should happen then?

Comment: @nayrb  "reaching 10k is hard enough" this is quite besides the point as the issue would arise at each privilege threshold, also the lower ones. Plus there is precedence of users with points in the thousands even ten thousands having cut their points to about half because of some irregularity.  On the rest, no one claims it would be impossible to have a different system, the claim is that what you want specifically would lead to some additional complications. Especially as I feel it is a bit of a half-way solution, and, it's illogical that timing of bounty should have a drastic effect.

Comment: @quid What are those irregularities? How often do they occur? How many people affected? 

There's already a sort of "orthogonal" reputation system, that's badges. Is that illogical or too complicated?

Comment: @AsafKaragila We are already dealing with trust. Someone with moderator tools can wreck havoc if they wanted. An ordinary user could wreck havoc as well. The only way to put a dent in 10k rep without bounties would be getting a massive number of penalties. Like I said, 9k vs 10k isn't much of a difference. We don't need moderators to check for this.

Comment: @quid I'm not aware of the various reputation thresholds. What are they?

Comment: @nayrb: None of the thresholds make sense, they are all arbitrary. Why 10k and not 12k or $2^{16}$? or any other number? This is not like temperature where we can equate this to relation between boiling point and atmospheric pressure and whatnot. It's yet another arbitrarily chosen cutoff point. If 9k to 10k is not a big difference, then either 9k should be enough, but then 8k, or at least 8.5k is also almost the same, and by induction, just give everyone every privilege. Now who's putting an incredible amount of vigor into their arguments? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Come on! =P It may not be clear exactly what sequence $r_1, r_2, r_3, \dots$ of reputation thresholds there should be, but it is relatively clear that $r_n = O(e^n)$. =) If you can't take that, then lets say that the least squares linear fit of $\log(r_n)$ should be relatively small. Or $e^n/C \leq r_n \leq C e^n$.

Comment: @nayrb: This is all finite talk. All finite integers are $O(1)$ anyway. Let me know when you reach the first strong limit cardinal which is also an $\aleph$ fixed point, which has a non-computable index as a $\beth$ number. :-P

Comment: Oh boy, imagine people obtaining non-finite reputations. How's that for practical!?

Comment: @nayrb what do you mean you are not aware of them? All the time you got new privileges did you really miss that? Voting, Commenting, Reviewing, Editing, Closing etc Here is the list http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges  // The absolute number of instances at that high level is certainly rare. The details of the irregularities are not disclose so I cannot know. But what I could note is users dropping by thousands of points. Again, everything could be done differently, but first I do not see the necessity  and second the specific details of your proposal are not good.

Comment: A main problem being that it is a half-way solution. If somebody where to propose to decouple bounties and privileges completely than alright let us discuss this. But you propose something else, namely that they stay couple just when you clear some threshold then you can keep this one indefinitely. That's strange in my opinion, as it would penalize somebody that gives out bounties regularly over somebody that makes it in a burst after clearing a threshold. @nayrb

Comment: @nayrb: Practical? Who cares. Pure math is not for practical purposes. It has its own beauty for its own sake. Especially set theory, with its elegance, and sleek veneer of "oh that is so frigging infinitely awesome".

Comment: @AsafKaragila, just out of curiosity, why are just invoking only this *set theory* always? Is there any specific reason (like teasing OP for some cause or like this), or just without any reason? You also included this into your answer.

Comment: @Subhadeep: If you look in my profile, and if you look at the top users in the set theory related tags, you might find out. And also if you read my profile, or check my homepage. This might give you a hint.

Comment: Oh OK! Found out. Thanks.

Comment: @Subhadeep, Asaf here writes set theory in the same way that birds fly and fish swim. ;)

Comment: @J.M.: You mean by instinct? Or perhaps as my parents taught me when I just got my flight feathers? No, I write set theory like someone who had been writing thousands of answers, many similar, and had been teaching set theory for six years, and have been spending the majority of his waking hours, and several of his dreaming days, in thinking about set theory and how it connects to mathematics. While I do appreciate the compliment, I write set theory the way I do as the culmination of many many years of shaping and experiencing life, writing and explaining things to others. And I enjoyed it all

Comment: I'm missing the point of this exercise: the SE people made the game and made the rules. We're just playing here, with a tacit agreement with the rules in place. Would you demand that the rules of Battleship be changed just because one hit beings you closer to sinking?

Comment: @Asaf: I mean you've gotten to the point where you can't help but inject set theory into stuff that's not traditionally the purview of set theory, like this situation. ;P

Comment: @J.M.: Of course I can. I *choose* not to not inject set theory intp certain things. :-P

Comment: @J.M., apart from most meta commenting being an idle exercise, the meta.SE question you linked had as many votes (more on the question, a few less on the answer) for the idea of keeping privileges that drop due to a bounty, as for losing them.   That question is also 7 years old, so I don't see why it could not be raised again if people were interested enough.

Comment: @zyx: And yet, [when this issue was raised again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267666/dont-remove-privileges-for-rep-given-to-bounties) not even a year ago, the reception was poor, and it got closed as a duplicate of that very old question. By a non-diamond user.

Comment: There was no good or bad reception of the idea when that question was posted, because it was closed as duplicate 40 minutes after posting. As a result it has been seen by very few users (54 page views in 8 months, compared to 1700 on the old question).

Comment: @zyx: If a -7 score is not reception, then we have some difference in the interpretation of the word. I don't think it means what you think it means. Reception need not mean "have hundreds of votes" (I can't even access the actual voting tally, so who knows? Maybe it has +60-67 or something? Is this still no reception?)

Comment: The *post* got a reception, by being closed as duplicate.  The *idea* did not get any reception in the sense of "revealing the views of the overall community", allowing discussion of that, or getting a meaningful sample.    The earliest votes come from the always online activist users and on meta.SE (as other sites) those tend to be hard-liners who oppose feature-requests.  The one-vote closing as duplicate is an example of that, and some of the voters may have wanted to push a duplicate toward autodeletion.  The question did not stay open long enough to reveal current opinion.

Comment: ^^ is essentially a repost of a comment that I was surprised to see deleted.

Comment: @J.M. We should ask to have the rules changed? What then, may I ask you, is the purpose of meta SE?

Comment: What you said, @nayrb: that's where we ask if the rules can be changed. Altho my Magic 8-Ball says "Outlook not so good" for your particular appeal.